# How to use lambda expression in Isabelle/HOL?

Tags: isabelle

In my exercise to learn Isabelle/HOL syntax, I tried to prove a toy lemma below. It's about lambda expressions (and things like the "Greatest" notation that takes a predicate as input). The intended content of the lemma is that "the greatest natural number that is l.e. 1 is 1".

```
lemma "1 = Greatest (λ x::nat. x ≤ 1)"
proof - 
  show ?thesis 
    by auto
qed
```

However, the above proof doesn't work either by `auto` or `simp`, and generates a message that.

```
Failed to finish proof⌂:
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. Suc 0 = (GREATEST x. x ≤ Suc 0)
```

Can someone help explain what went wrong with the statement or how to prove this correctly (if the statement is correct)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the lemma, it's just that none of the rules for `Greatest` are declared in such a way that `auto` knows about them. Which is probably good, because these kinds of rules tend to mess with automation a lot.

You can prove your statement using e.g. the rule `Greatest_equality`:

```
lemma "1 = Greatest (λ x::nat. x ≤ 1)"
proof - 
  have "(GREATEST (x::nat). x ≤ 1) = 1"
    by (rule Greatest_equality) auto
  thus ?thesis by simp
qed
```

You can find rules like this using the Query panel in Isabelle/jEdit or the `find_theorems` command by searching for the constant `Greatest`.

If the `GREATEST` thing confuses you, the syntax `GREATEST x. P x` is just fancy syntax for `Greatest (λx. P x)`. Such notation is fairly standard in Isabelle, we also have `∃x. P x` for `Ex (λx. P x)` etc.